# how can I use opencv to run the java code

Tags: opencv

I have opencv10.05 installed in my laptop and I was working on tracking with c++. Now I have one project that I have to run the code in java with opencv. Is it possible to use same opencv10.05 or do I need to install the whole steup?

Comment: wow, you are living in the future, they did not even finish opencv3.0 yet ;)

Comment: Maybe it's 1.0.0-5, but if it is indeed 10.05, i gotta update:).

Answer (score 1):

opencv comes with its [own java bindings](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro). you will need cmake, ant, and the opencv src code to build it.

javacv is a 3rd party wrapper, unfortunately mostly based on opencv's deprecated 1.0 c-api, so you will have to program java, like it was in c years ago. mixed blessing..

Comment: Isn't that for Android only?